# Why isn't this question community-wiki?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, community-wiki

I've seen this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/871050)

It's a very popular one on StackOverflow, and I've noticed something, it's not community wiki.

According to [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), a question should become CW ones it accumulated 30 answers, <s>that one has 37</s><sub>didn't notice 21 of those were deleted, so it doesn't count</sub>.

Also, the first, accepted answer, **used to be** CW, and is now no longer one. The answer was very heavily community-edited, and I don't think a single user should receive reputation for it.

Why aren't those posts community wiki?

Comment: Note that 21 of those answers are deleted. They don't count towards the 30 needed to get auto-wikied.

Comment: @Mysticial: That explains the first part

Comment: For the accepted answer, only the owner and PeeHaa seems to have contributed any "real" content to the post. The rest are mostly formatting and grammar fixes. Personally, I don't consider that enough to be considered a "community" effort.

Comment: @Mysticial: What is the logic for posts automatically becoming community wiki when the OP makes 10 edits? In such a case, the OP might be the only person to have contributed *any* content (let alone "real" content).

Comment: @eggyal Abusive bumping. I don't agree with that reason since since abusive bumpers should be auto-flagged for moderator attention instead.

Comment: @Mysticial: Is that really the reason?  If so, I completely agree that moderator attention is a better response than automatic conversion to CW.

Comment: I would rather you took it to chat, rather than spamming my inbox. If you may.

Comment: @eggyal Yes it is. There have been multiple feature requests to change it to a moderator flag. But they all fell on deaf ears.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't speak to why the question hasn't had community wiki status imposed upon it, but the answer was flagged by its owner, who requested that the community wiki status be removed. He didn't choose to make the answer community wiki, it was forced into that by the large number of edits from a single person. In such situations, we almost always obey the request of the answerer and remove the community wiki status.

Community wiki is there to promote editing on list-style answers or other things that require community collaboration. No such promotion was needed here, as the answer was fine by itself and was just added on to by a couple of users.

Comment: I always thought community wiki status is given to a post when no single user deserves reputation from it. Since this question would not have reached its final status by itself (or, by the owner's self) I don't think he deserves reputation from it. Looks like repwhoring to me. Also, very little answers genuinely need "edit promotion", and the concept of community-wiki was very reduced once suggested edits came into being. If the OP's requests will always be honored, why have the automatic system at all?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - It seems a bit harsh to accuse a 25k user of "repwhoring" when they didn't choose to have community wiki status added to their answer and simply wanted that reversed. If we all started worrying about who deserves credit for edits to questions and answers, I fear that would lead us down a path that discourages edits. I'm not convinced that the automatic imposition of community wiki for a set number of edits has a place here anymore, given how the use of wiki status has changed in recent years. I might put in a feature request about that.

Comment: I hope I don't need to remind you that nearly a third of his rep came from that answer. I'll accept this answer. Doesn't mean I like it though.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted answers don't count towards the overall total "answers" for CW conversion, only visible ones. There are only 16 answers to that question.

It is also possible for moderators to un-convert a post from CW status. How do you know it used to be community wiki? The notice is completely removed from the post when CW is undone. As far as *why* it might have been undone, only a moderator could tell you that.

Comment: I know it used to be CW because the edit I submitted caused it to be CW.

Comment: Also, I was hoping to get a moderator's answer on this